# Python reading file error

Tags: python, file, machine-learning, pycharm

I'm trying to read a list of number from a text file and I am getting this error when I run my code:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): -4.4987000e-01 -2.0049000e-01  -4.8729000e-01  -6.1085000e-02  -5.1024000e-02  -2.1653000e-02
```

Here is my code:

```
def read_data_file(datafile, token):

    dataset = []
    with open(datafile, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            #split each word by token
            data = line[:-1].split(token)
            tmp = []
            for x in data:
                if x != "":
                    x = float(x)
                    tmp.append(x)
                else:
                    tmp.append(1e+99)
            dataset.append(tmp)
    return dataset
```

The program encounter the error at the line: x = float(x)

Comment: The line is not being split properly. Check that the value of `token` matches the delimiter used in the file.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your `datafile`? Or at least print out `x` right before the assignment `x = float(x)` and show us that.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided the full code and data file to reproduce your problem exactly.  But it's possible to guess your issue from the error message.

Your `line[:-1].split(token)` failed to break up `line` into single-number strings.  Either you picked an incorrect separator (`token` is a poor choice of name), or/and omitting the last character from `line` broke it.

Try this (also reducing many unnecessary lines)

```
def read_data_file(datafile):
    dataset = []
    for line in open(datafile, 'r'):  
    # no need to assign open() to file, it will be closed when for is done
        dataset.append( [ float(token) for token in line.split() ] )
        # default (separator=None) works for most situations

        dataset.append(1e+99)
        # do you really need to append a fake number?
        # a better way might be a list of lists
    return dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the data in your file is on one line, like below:

`-4.4987000e-01 -2.0049000e-01 -4.8729000e-01 -6.1085000e-02 -5.1024000e-02 -2.1653000e-02`

I made a few adjustments and ran your code as below and it worked. It may not be what you want, but if that's the case then you need to be more specific as to what you want. If the data in your file doesn't look like the above then you also need to show us exactly how it resides in your file.

```
def read_data_file(datafile, token):
    dataset = []
    with open(datafile, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            #split each word by token
            data = line[:-1].split(token)
            tmp = []
            for x in data:
                if x != "":
                    x = float(x)
                    tmp.append(x)
                else:
                    tmp.append(1e+99)
            dataset.append(tmp)
    return dataset

dataset = read_data_file('test_data.txt',  ' ')
print(dataset)
# output
'''
[[-0.44987, -0.20049, -0.48729, -0.061085, -0.051024, -0.021653]]
'''
```

As mention, using `token` as a parameter is not a good choice but it will work. If your data is always going to be space separated and on a single line then do away with a 'token' and do this: `data = line[:-1].split(' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.strip` to remove any trailing space. And the split by the required token. And you can use `map` to apply float on each element on list.

**Ex:**

```
def read_data_file(datafile, token):
    dataset = []
    with open(datafile, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            #split each word by token
            dataset.append(map(float, map(float, line.strip().split(token))))
    return dataset
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to provide a check before you call float to make sure there are no other data that will cause the float function to result in the error. Usually it is the character \x00. You will need to call something like

```
filtered_value = x.replace("\x00", "")
filtered_value = float(filtered_value)
tmp.append(filtered_value)
```